# Convert cron rule to epoch timestamp in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, cron, timestamp, epoch

I have a bunch of cron rules (say */10 0 0 0 0, */10 2 3 * *) and I need to convert them in epoch timestamp format (UINT32). I know that a cron rules can be mapped either to a finite set of timepoints (no asterisk in the rule) or to infinite timepoints (at least one asterisk in the rule) so asking for a simple 1:1 conversion is a non-sense in any practical form.

My only requirement is to compute the epoch timestamp of the NEXT occurrence of that cron rule w.r.t. the current time

Any suggestions on how to do so in C++ ?

Comment: Only the bruteforce approach: incrementing the current time by 1 and comparing it against the rule. Store the first timestamp that would match the cron rule.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: which is exactly what I want to do ;)

Comment: Ah, misread your question... Anyway, why don't you look at how an actual cron program does it? There are plenty of open-source variants (both BSD and GPL) that you can use for reference.